# Laravel Guzzle jobs failure, kills queue until restart (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host:)

Tags: laravel, redis, guzzle

using Laravel Horizon to run our queues on Redis but keep running into the same error.

Almost a daily occurrence, we will suddenly get a Guzzle curl error that seems to wipe out all jobs at once any that are added after that.

The only way to get the jobs to work again is to restart the queue / terminate horizon which we now have on a schedule.

There's not one particular job that causes the error but it's always down to Guzzle.

An example of the Guzzle error would be:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: login.salesforce.com
```

The other odd thing is that the timestamps for all the failed jobs with this error are at the same second so it's almost like it just wipes them all out together without trickling through the queue.

I've been Googling this a while but not come across the same issue that only randomly happens.

This seems to have only started with switching to Redis / Horizon too.

Comment: Do you handle the exceptions with try-catch?

Comment: catch the exception `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException` it will solve it

Comment: @bhucho The exception is thrown in a package that is called on every request so it's not part of the job code.

Interestingly, this only happens on the default queue. Once the error happens it will affect every job until queue restarted.

Switched the queue on the job and worked fine.

Comment: so after error is thrown how is it handled if handled then you can either rerun the job from catch or use a do while to check till it connects and check after 2min for connection

Comment: if the connection goes off it will throw connect exception if it is not able to connect it will break the cron you need to record that it has stopped and rerun once stopped